# Delphi replace string with callback

Tags: regex, delphi, replace, callback, delphi-xe2

In JavaScript it is possible to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) string with callback that takes matches as arguments using regular expressions.

```js
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string){
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
};
newString = "abc12345#$*%".replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Delphi? I tried to search but did not find anything useful.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not a similar function in Delphi, but you can build your own using [`anonymous methods`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/anonymousmethods_xml.html) and [`regular expressions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will read that and try to do something. I hoped that Delphi has some built-in functions for that.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but fyi, `[^\d]` is synonymous with `\D`, and `[^\w]` with `\W`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Delphi's `TPerlRegEx` class has an `OnReplace` event handler that is called by the `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` methods for each replacement.  You can use this event handler to achieve the same that you'd use a callback for in JavaScript.

In addition, the `TRegEx.Replace` method has overloads that take a `TMatchEvaluator` parameter.  This type is a function reference which is used as a callback just like in JavaScript.